# Usage of C Block Scope in Interrupt Handler?

Tags: c, arm, embedded, cpu

Is there any advantage or disadvantage of using a C block scope in a function or specifically inside an Interrupt Handler?

From the link - http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0472i/CJAIIDCG.html - Refer stack usage.

In general, you can lower the stack requirements of your program by:

1. Writing small functions that only require a small number of variables.
2. Avoiding the use of large local structures or arrays.
3. Avoiding recursion, for example, by using an alternative algorithm.
4. Minimizing the number of variables that are in use at any given time at each p oint in a function.
5. **Using C block scope and declaring variables only where they are required, so overlapping the memory used by distinct scopes.**

Advantage or disadvantage in using the C block Scope is not very clear.

Comment: This is a vey broad question asking for an opinion, so not very well suited to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I don't think there's a required link between how variable declarations are scoped, and how the compiler chooses to use the stack space for them.

Comment: Overall rule of thumb for interrupt handlers: keep it simple.

Comment: Overall rule of thumb for ISRs (II): Don't let it allocate ressources if you don't need to. Allocating stack in block scope is a ressource allocation (albeit a simple one). If I'd had to endure some stack overflow, I'd rather have it in application code than in an ISR, so I'd generally use already allocated memory in an ISR.

Answer (score 2):

If you write:

```
{
    int foo[1000];
    int bar[1000];
    … code that uses foo …
    … code that uses bar …
}
```

then `foo` and `bar` exist for the entire block and must use different memory. (The compiler/optimizer may recogize they are not used simultaneously and arrange to use the same memory, but various things can interfere with this, so you cannot rely on it.)

If you write:

```
{
    {
        int foo[1000];
        … code that uses foo …
    }
    {
        int bar[1000];
        … code that uses bar …
    }
}
```

Then `foo` and `bar` only exist at different times, so the compiler can use the same memory for them.

Comment: Of course, if you're allocating a K on your stack in an ISR, you probably already doing the wrong thing :-)

Comment: In my experience, a compiler may create a stack frame for all function variables regardless of scope such that within the function the scope affects only the visibility. not the lifetime. YMMV but I would not rely on this.

Answer (score 0):

This just means that the compiler *can* optimize the space required by the execution of a function if you limit the life-time of variables using more scopes. Considering something like

```
int x;
// [some code]
int y;
// [some code not using x]
```

The compiler must still keep `x` until the end of the function. If you instead structure it like this:

```
{
    int x;
    // [some code]
}
{
    int y;
    // [some code not using x]
}
```

`x` doesn't exist in the code using `y`, so the compiler **may** reuse the same space that was earlier occupied by `x` (and it is quite likely that a compiler will indeed do that).

---

General note: If you have to think about this in an ISR, your ISR is probably already **too big**. Keep ISRs as minimal and fast as possible -- e.g. enqueuing an event might be a good action for an ISR.

Comment: Logically, the compiler needs to keep x until the end of the function.  But in practice, it will not normally do so if the optimiser is enabled - it will keep x around only as long as it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use blocks in your C code to make the code clear and logical.  This applies to *all* C programming - not just in interrupts.  It is usually a good idea to define your local variables only within the scope where they will be used.  (Don't go overboard on this and define new scopes just for your variables - but if a variable is used only within a loop or a branch of a conditional, define it within that block.)

As long as you are using an optimising compiler (and the optimisation is enabled!), there is rarely a difference in stack space and usage when you have your local variables inside a block or outside.  The compiler will be smart enough to see the useful lifetime of the variable, and limit its allocation appropriately.

And if you are *not* using optimisation with your compiler - you should be!